# Return Object List of Specific Derived Type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I should preface this by saying that this will implemented in Unity, so I may use some functions and class names from there, but here goes:

I have a class for the possible item types in my game that will be stored in a JSON file:

```
public class Item
{
    //Properties galore
}

public class Weapon : Item
{
    //All my weapon stats
}

public class Projectile : Weapon
{
    //All my projectile weapon stats
}
```

So now I can pull in a bunch of stats and weapons. My player's current inventory, for example, is stored in a list:

```
List<Item> playerInventory = new List<Item>();

//And then I go on and add my inventory items from a stored file, etc.
```

So poof, now my player has an inventory. Yay. Unfortunately, I'm struggling to figure out a way to get a list of JUST Weapons, or JUST Projectile Weapons. I could add a "type" parameter to my JSON file that holds the defaults for each weapon, etc., but it seems like C# would have a way to do something clever like

```
List<Weapon> weaponList = new List<Weapon>();

foreach(Item<Weapon> i in playerInventory)
{
   weaponList.Add(i);
}
```

I know, I know, this isn't right at all, but hopefully you get my point. It doesn't have be exactly like that of course, but I figured there must be a way to turn a list of Items into a new list of Weapons relatively painlessly.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Get a list of just weapons out of where? The JSON? Or `playerInventory`?

Comment: Hey, sorry, I suppose I didn't specify, I'm trying to get the list of Weapons out my list of Items. Because my Item list may contain more than Weapons, so I'm trying to get ONLY those entries that are of the Weapon type.

Answer (score 2):

for your use case, you can't use `OfType` because it's check the type of the object using `is` operator (returns **all objects in the inheritance tree**)

I suggest you write an extension method

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TType> IsTypeOf<TType>(this IEnumerable input)
        where TType : class
    {
        foreach (object o in input)
        {
            if (o.GetType() == typeof(TType)) // take note of this, don't use is
            {
                yield return (TType)o;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

How to use

```
var playerInventory = new List<Item>();

playerInventory.Add(new Weapon());
playerInventory.Add(new Weapon());
playerInventory.Add(new Weapon());
playerInventory.Add(new Weapon());
playerInventory.Add(new Projectile());
playerInventory.Add(new Projectile());

// player inventory should have 4 weapons
playerInventory.IsTypeOf<Weapon>().Should().HaveCount(4);
// player inventory should have 2 projectiles
playerInventory.IsTypeOf<Projectile>().Should().HaveCount(2);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I do not understand your comment about `OfType()`, which is the obvious answer. There is nothing in the question that implies that a search for weapons should exclude specialized weapons; indeed that would make no sense at all if `Weapon` is abstract.

Comment: The built-in LINQ function OfType will return you all items (projectiles and weapon) which is not what OP wants, he wants to have two sublists, one contains ONLY weapons and one contains ONLY projectiles

Comment: Yes, I understand the different behaviors, but I guess I am in disagreement over the requirement. If it did turn out to be the case that you are correct, I feel an appropriate answer would be to steer the OP to an object model that is more consistent with the notion of inheritance; surely a list of guns would include both rifles *and* pistols. More importantly, it violates [LSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-an-example-of-the-liskov-substitution-principle), and will cause common operations to become error-prone chores if the logic is later extended.

Comment: Hey Kien! Thank you! Your solution is the only one that didn't return errors. Ironically, the programming gods have decided that for not returning any errors, it won't return anything else either. It doesn't pass me back any data. Any thoughts? I'm more than happy to post my full testing code if you'd like.

Comment: @JohnWu: **Unfortunately, I'm struggling to figure out a way to get a list of JUST Weapons, or JUST Projectile Weapons.** - OP. I disagree on the LSP violation, there are a couple of reasons (which don't violate LSP)  I can think of why OP wants it such a way. Let's say you wanna count how many items of a specific object type (e.g how many riffles?, how many pistols?).

Comment: @SloanPhillippi: `var weapons = playerInventory.IsTypeOf<Weapon>();`

Comment: Currently, we are doing:
`var weapons = playerInventory.IsTypeOf<Weapon>();
List<Weapon> = weapons.ToList<Weapon>();`
But we get no list items. Are we missing something that's right in front of our faces?

Comment: you don't need the second line of code, you only need this `var weapons = playerInventory.IsTypeOf<Weapon>();`, and `weapons` contains all the objects you need

Comment: "Just weapons" to me means *all items that are weapons*, which naturally includes anything that inherits from a weapon. If you asked for a list of animals, does that mean you don't want dogs and cats and horses? No. This is not exactly a controversial interpretation; the very meaning of inheritance is that the subtype is a specialization of the supertype. Perhaps the right answer is to remove the inheritance relationship. The correct answer is *not* direct type comparison, unless you want a very brittle design.

Comment: @JohnWu I finally understand where you were coming from now. Agree with you on this. But, let's say if have a method which only takes **dogs** as input parameter, and you want to extract all the **dogs** from your **animal** list to pass into the method. What do you think? I believe `is operator` & `exact type comparison` both have their own usages and our job is to figure out when to use what. Cheers

Comment: @KienChu If there is functional logic that depends on the type, that logic should be implemented *within* the type, e.g. you could write a virtual method that chooses which service to send the animal to and override it for dogs. You don't want code outside of the class inspecting the type and making decisions based on it; that would be a  [leaky abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction). Otherwise, every time you subclass something, you'd have to go back over the code in your factories and repositories and make sure all that type-specific logic does what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using linq:

```
List<Item> inventory = new List<Item>();
// Fill inventory with items of different type.

List<Weapon> weapons = inventory.Where(item => item.GetType() == typeof(Weapon)).Cast<Weapon>().ToList();
List<Projectile> weapons = inventory.Where(item => item.GetType() == typeof(Projectile)).Cast<Projectile>().ToList();
```

Make sure you add `using System.Linq;` for it to work.

Comment: This also won't work since `IEnumerable` is covariant. You will need to cast the item, not the enumeration, e.g. with [`Cast<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx) so `inventory.Where( blah ).Cast<Weapon>().ToList()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ's [OfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) method to filter the list. This also casts the results to the proper type automatically.

```
var weapons = inventory.OfType<Weapon>();
var projectiles = inventory.OfType<Projectile>();
```

Note that your object model indicates that a Projectile is a type of Weapon (this is what an inheritance relationship means) so in my example, `weapons` will contain projectiles as well.

If you wish to exclude certain things (e.g. get a list of all weapons that are not projectiles) you can use an additional `Where` clause for special filtering.

```
var nonProjectileWeapons = inventory
    .OfType<Weapon>()
    .Where
    (
        weapon => !(weapon is Projectile) 
    );
```

In all cases the above will return an `IEnumerable<Weapon>`, which is all you usually need. If you need an actual concrete `List`, just add `ToList()` to the end.

```
List<Weapon> nonProjectileWeapons = inventory
    .OfType<Weapon>()
    .Where
    (
        weapon => !(weapon is Projectile) 
    )
    .ToList();
```

Of course if you want only instances of the specific concrete class `Weapon` (assuming it is concrete-- it probably should be abstract), you can perform a direct comparison of the type in the where clause. For completeness I'll give you an example, but I strongly suggest you revisit your object model if you find yourself doing things like this. If a projectile weapon does not belong in a list of weapons, they should not have an inheritance relationship; perhaps you need some other concept in your model-- for example, perhaps Weapon and ProjectileWeapon should both inherit from BaseWeapon, but have no inheritance relationship between each other.

Anyway, here it is.

```
List<Weapon> unspecializedWeapons = inventory
    .OfType<Weapon>()
    .Where
    (
        weapon => weapon.GetType() == typeof(Weapon) 
    )
    .ToList();
```

Comment: your method works but it's not extensible, let's say you have (n) hierarchy depths, you will need to check (n) times. Also, if you add new object in the inheritance hierarchy, you will need to update your condition everywhere

Comment: This solution is extensible in an object oriented way. You can add additional types of weapons and they will be included; you can add additional types of projectiles and they will be excluded. What's more, unlike direct type-equality comparison, it will work with abstraction, interfaces, and mainstream OO design. This ridiculous notion that a supertype isn't a generalization of its subtypes is the problem, and we should be steering the OP away from that, if that is what he even meant.